# how to make the player not rotate when i press left or right button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Did someone know how to make the player not turning when i press left or right button ? I'm using unity script refrence for moving.

this video showing my problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m-_Q3j0kt5bMfxiiqqjGAp0wtW7x8gno/view?usp=sharing

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 playerVelocity;
private bool groundedPlayer;
private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

private void Start()
{
    controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }

    // Changes the height position of the player..
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```cs
if (move != Vector3.zero)
{
    gameObject.transform.forward = move;
}
```